# AWS Ops work vs ( base-image + code deploy + autoscaling )

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, deployment, aws-opsworks

Currently, to make infrastructure HA and scalable using AWS I am using following components.

1. `base-image` -- Which will be used by `autoscale` to launch new instances during high traffic.
2. `auto-scale` -- I have configured `autoscaling` policies which launch new instances using above `base-image`.
3. `code-deploy`  -- Whenever new `instance` gets launched by `autoscale`, `code-deploy` deploy the latest successful revision to that instance.
   Best thing is about code-deploy is that if current deployment fails then it will rollback to previous successful revision.
4. `jenkins` -- I have integrated `jenkins` with code-deploy so that if there is commit on `master` branch then after running test cases it triggers `code-deploy` .

Note : `base-image` has a `chef-client` kept under cron job. Whenever new instance launched by `autoscale` it gets registered in `chef-server` and if I push any `new/updated` recipes it is automatically deployed to respective nodes through `chef-client`.

I am thinking it is pretty much good architecture BUT then I come across `opswork` .

Will I be able to achieve pretty much same functionality with `opswork` OR should I go with my current setup ?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a client (that includes chef) in the opsworks os images, but chef runs in solo mode (ie no central server). You can pretty much replicate what you have with Opsworks but you're going to give up some of the flexibility and control you have.

What I would do is take your setup ever further and make it awesome by using CloudFormation to spin up a new stack every time you deploy and shift traffic from the old stack to the new stack. This is also awesome for keeping multiple environments for test, preprod and prod.

Comment: thanks for replying. Would like to know that the structure I have setup is good to go ?? Are there any major flaws in current setup. I will look into cloud formation.

Comment: it's a reasonable setup. You have more flexibility, but you're trading off some of the convenience of opsworks. jenkins and the chef server are the weak points in your setup. Either of them going down is probably bad. Would look at how their failure might impact you / the setup.